# How to detect change of variable with formula

Tags: javascript, variables

I have this variable (levelFormula) that contains a formula and then is updated via the output of another variable

```
     var points = 100,
         levelFormula = (Math.sqrt(2 * points + 255) - 5) / 10;
```

In other words, if *points* gets updated then so does *levelFormula*. The question is, how do I detect when the value of *levelFormula* gets changed?

Comment: to detect the changes, you should keep the previous value of levelFormula in some other variable

Comment: Apologies, how do I do that, Mr. Choi?

Comment: you can create a variable which stores previous `levelFormula`. and set as undefined as default then when it's defined but not the same with `levelFormula`, you can assume it's changed.

Comment: Could you share a sample code because I might need some more help? Thank you for your time, Mr. Choi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments,

```
var previousLevelFormula; // should be separated with below scope

...
var points = 100; // I guess it's from function parameter, because it will be changed so you need detection changes of levelFormula
var levelFormula = (Math.sqrt(2 * points + 255) - 5) / 10;

if (previousLevelFormula && previousLevelFormula != levelFormula) {
  // it's changed
}

previousLevelFormula = levelFormula; // update previous value
```

Comment: Is there a reason why previousLevelFormula was mentioned twice in the "if" statement? By the way, thank you so much for your help. You're the best

Comment: because `previousLevelFormula` is undefined at first check.